# Database Error for Mysql Database Design for an Online Student Monitoring System

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

A true beginner in Mysql.  I hope you can help me find the error in my code here.  I am making a database for my Online Student Monitoring System.  Please help me find the error and give me tips to improve on my Database Design.

I keep receiving this fOllowing error here:
MYSQL error: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Thank you Very Much in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was able to solve the problem by removing all connections, and putting it again.

Kinda weird at my part.